# Telegram Database Library (TDLib) in Vue project

Tags: vue.js, telegram, tdlib

I'd like to use the Telegram Messaging system for my plattform's real time communication.

Is it possible that I can make my users search each other and add them to a chat on my vue site?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's technically possible, but why would you need it? Telegram has rather closed ecosystem despite of technical openness, so you'll need to implement a semi-client, and your visitors should trust your website to log into their Telegram accounts from it. You could be inspired by the Facebook Messenger widget, but this widget securely runs on Facebook side, and Telegram does not provide a similar solution. Though, if you need the visitors only to reach each other and to continue communicating via official apps, then TDlib and one (your) account to get their profile info are perfectly enough.

Comment: but why would you need it? In my case.. i use telegram for send receive data in my server.. its secure  ..  on message recieive or data from my server i can customise like table chart or anything in vue app project .. and also i have a small comunity where trust to login from my website / my app